# Issue while using dat.GUI in a three.js example

Tags: javascript, user-interface, three.js, dat.gui

I tried to use [dat.GUI](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) in the following three.js [example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_vtk.html).

I just did the following code changes to add a GUI to adjust mesh opacity.

```js
var loader=new THREE.VTKLoader();
loader.load ("models/vtk/bunny.vtk", function(geom){
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material );
mesh.doubleSided=true;
mesh.position.setY(-0.09);
scene.add( mesh );

var gui = new dat.GUI();

var view = this;
view.Opacity = 0.2;

var maingui = gui.addFolder('Main');
var opacity = maingui.add(view, 'Opacity', 0, 1);
opacity.onChange( function(value) {
    mesh.material.opacity = value;
});

maingui.open();

animate();
```

Now, once I click the opacity slider the mouse is just following the slider. I am not able to come out of the mouse click.

Comment: Have you tried a console.log in the opacity.onChange function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Move the controls init block after the renderer init block, and change this line:

```js
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
```

to this:

```js
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Answer (score 1):

Old subject but I just have a similar issue and previous solution wasn't ok for my case. To fix it I create a specific canvas for the dat.gui module:

Html part:

```
<div id="my-gui-container"></div>
```

Css part:

```
#my-gui-container{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Js Part:

```
this.gui = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false });

var customContainer = document.getElementById('my-gui-container');
customContainer.appendChild(this.gui.domElement);
```

With this method the elements are isolate and I have no event conflict anymore.

**Edit**: 
for more details you have all code here https://github.com/quentinchap/threeJs-morphing-test

Answer (score 0):

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var trackballControls;


function render() {
stats.update();
        var delta = clock.getDelta();   
        trackballControls.update(delta);

        // render using requestAnimationFrame
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);    
    }


    function trackBall(){
        trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, render.domElement) ;

        trackballControls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
        trackballControls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
        trackballControls.panSpeed = 1.0;
        //  trackballControls.noZoom=false;
        //trackballControls.noPan=false;
        trackballControls.staticMoving = true;
        //trackballControls.dynamicDampingFactor=0.3;
    }


        trackBall();

        render();
```

I changed my code as shown in the example to
"`THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement)`" 
but I still effect my GUI when I used it once and can't deselect it from this moment. Is there any possibility to deactivate or to deselect the active GUI parts with a command? or something like "gui.deselect.all" ?