# Three.js trackball controls drag event not working in UIkit modal

Tags: javascript, three.js, uikit

Situation is as follows: I've got a fullscreen Three.js canvas where all is working perfectly fine, but I have to show a preview in a UIkit modal. There the controls only work partially: Zooming works, panning does not.

**JS: Renderer and Controls**

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true
});
// renderer size
if (typeof size === "object") {
  renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
} else {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
$(canvas).append(renderer.domElement);

renderer.gammaInput = true;
renderer.gammaOutput = true;

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.cullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;

controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.rotateSpeed = 10;
controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;
controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

controls.keys = [65, 83, 68];

controls.addEventListener("change", render);
```

As you can see in the above code sample I instantiate the Controls after the renderer avoiding the situation described in [this thread and solved by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359046). Also the controls object gets explicitly bound to the renderers DOM element to avoid blocking of other events.

It seems like the UIkit modal somehow catches all drag events.

I reproduced the scenario in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4h821681/10/).

Did anyone of you encounter a similiar situation and found a solution or at least a workaround?

Comment: Your current fiddle links the TrackballControls.js incorrectly. Here is a [fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/4h821681/10/).

Comment: Thanks, @LeJeuneRenard. Edited question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIkit modal is not catching the drag events. Your problem is that the `TrackballControls` calculates the `domElement`'s size while the element is hidden, hence has zero dimensions.

What you need to do is update the control's understand of the `domElement`'s size once the modal is open and hence the `domElement` is the proper dimensions:

```
$('#modal').on('show.uk.modal', function(){
  var cachedControl = controlsMap['#dialog-canvas']
  cachedControl.handleResize(); // Recalculate size
});
```

Here is a [fiddle with the change](https://jsfiddle.net/4h821681/11/).

Here is the documentation on [UI Kit's modal events](http://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html#javascript).